# Not all items are selected in recyclerview android

Tags: android

In my `OnBindViewHolder`I've added the following code:

```
    if(checkAllItems) {
       viewHolder.checked_for_deletion.setChecked(true);
    } else {
       viewHolder.checked_for_deletion.setChecked(false);
    }
```

The problem is that `OnBindViewHolder` is only called for visible items + the cached items which is 2 by default. I need to select also the items that are not visible. I've looked around for solutions but couldn't find any that worked.

Comment: Then obviously you should store it in model class not view ...

Comment: Do you want to delete all items in recycler view? If yes why not just clear your list instead of doing that in onBindViewHolder. If you just want to show ticked items then your current code does fine

Comment: I think I've gone about this all wrong, I do store it in the datamodel class, but only based on if they are checked or not in the view. What I should do is loop trough the datamodel and rather check them there and check in the onbindview if they are checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot check all the items when binding the `ViewHolder`.

That is because only a certain number of `ViewHolder`s are created at once (to fill your `RecyclerView`). These `ViewHolder`s are then "recycled" as they pass out of the bounds of the `RecyclerView`. They are reused for future rows of content.

What you need to do is hold the state of the `CheckBox` in your data model. Then, you check whether the `CheckBox` needs to be checked with each call of `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: I know this and I do store it in the data model. So what you're saying is that if a click a button that checks all items. I should loop trough the datamodel and set them to checked and in the onbindviewholder check if they are checked and then set them accordingly.

Comment: Precisely. If you set click a button that must set all items checked, then you should set all those items to checked in your data source. When you get that information again simply check that value as to whether the CheckBox should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did based on the answers above, for some reason I had to change the model based on the view. This doesn't work for obvious reasons since not all items are displayed in the view. I iterated trough the modellist and checked them there.

```
            checkbox_selectAllListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                int c = 0;
                if(isChecked) {

                    for (TaskModel iterable_element : mDataset) {
                       iterable_element.setCheckedForDeletion(true);
                        Log.e("Setting checked ", ""+ c);
                        c++;
                    }
                } else {
                    for (TaskModel iterable_element : mDataset) {
                        iterable_element.setCheckedForDeletion(false);
                    }

                    Log.e("Setting unchecked ", ""+ c);
                    c++;
                }


                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

Comment: Depending on your datasource, if you use Sqlite, it might be simpler for you to do all updates in a second call. Right now, you mgiht be doing quite an expensive call on your database. If you do `Model.setAllChecked(true);` you will likely have a better experience. `UPDATE table SET checked=true` for example.

Comment: I'm using SharedPreferences to store the data, the data sent to the adapter is a filtered list of the items in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Ahhh, then you can't really help it. OK.

Comment: I'm having issues now where I want to check the items individually.

Comment: Because you are setting them all either on or off when one of them is changed. You should update the checked value in your data source for only the one that must be changed. You can move your "check all" logic to a button or menu item.

Comment: I solved it by turning off the oncheckedchanged listener when selecting or deselecting all of them. When I check them individually I just call notifyItemChanged(position);